# XCode Coordinates for iPad Retina Displays

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I just noticed an interesting thing while attempting to update my app for the new iPad Retina display, every coordinate in Interface Builder is still based on the original 1024x768 resolution.

What I mean by this is that if I have a 2048x1536 image to have it fit the entire screen on the display I need to set it's size to 1024x768 and not 2048x1536.

I am just curious is this intentional? Can I switch the coordinate system in Interface Builder to be specific for Retina? It is a little annoying since some of my graphics are not exactly 2x in either width or height from their originals. I can't seem to set 1/2 coordinate numbers such as 1.5 it can either be 1 or 2 inside of Interface Builder.

Should I just do my interface design in code at this point and forget interface builder? Keep my graphics exactly 2x in both directions? Or just live with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interface on iOS is based on points, not pixels. The images HAVE to be 2x the size of the originals.

> > Points Versus Pixels In iOS there is a distinction between the coordinates you specify in your drawing code and the pixels of the
> >     underlying device. When using native drawing technologies such as
> >     Quartz, UIKit, and Core Animation, you specify coordinate values using
> >     a logical coordinate space, which measures distances in points. This
> >     logical coordinate system is decoupled from the device coordinate
> >     space used by the system frameworks to manage the pixels on the
> >     screen. The system automatically maps points in the logical coordinate
> >     space to pixels in the device coordinate space, but this mapping is
> >     not always one-to-one. This behavior leads to an important fact that
> >     you should always remember:
>
> One point does not necessarily correspond to one pixel on the screen.
>   The purpose of using points (and the logical coordinate system) is to
>   provide a consistent size of output that is device independent. The
>   actual size of a point is irrelevant. The goal of points is to provide
>   a relatively consistent scale that you can use in your code to specify
>   the size and position of views and rendered content. How points are
>   actually mapped to pixels is a detail that is handled by the system
>   frameworks. For example, on a device with a high-resolution screen, a
>   line that is one point wide may actually result in a line that is two
>   pixels wide on the screen. The result is that if you draw the same
>   content on two similar devices, with only one of them having a
>   high-resolution screen, the content appears to be about the same size
>   on both devices.
>
> In your own drawing code, you use points most of the time, but there
>   are times when you might need to know how points are mapped to pixels.
>   For example, on a high-resolution screen, you might want to use the
>   extra pixels to provide extra detail in your content, or you might
>   simply want to adjust the position or size of content in subtle ways.
>   In iOS 4 and later, the UIScreen, UIView, UIImage, and CALayer classes
>   expose a scale factor that tells you the relationship between points
>   and pixels for that particular object. Before iOS 4, this scale factor
>   was assumed to be 1.0, but in iOS 4 and later it may be either 1.0 or
>   2.0, depending on the resolution of the underlying device. In the future, other scale factors may also be possible.

From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional on Apple's part, to make your code relatively independent of the actual screen resolution when positioning controls and text. However, as you've noted, it can make displaying graphics at max resolution for the device a bit more complicated.

For iPhone, the screen is always 480 x 320 points. For iPad, it's 1024 x 768. If your graphics are properly scaled for the device, the impact is not difficult to deal with in code. I'm not a graphic designer, and it's proven a bit challenging to me to have to provide multiple sets of icons, launch images, etc. to account for hi-res.

Apple has naming standards for some image types that minimize the impact on your code:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

That doesn't help you when you're dealing with custom graphics inline, however.